# How to replace a newline character with row number in Postgres / sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to replace a new line character with row number within a string  based on id following is the sample from one row from a table ,table has so many rows and each row should starts with 1.and so on.

```
sample data 
I
am
Awesome 

desired out put 
1.I 
2.am 
3.Awesome  

I tried to replace newline with rownumber but no success

select concat(1.,replace(field,char(10),cast(1+row_number()over(order by field) as varchar),'.') as desired_Formula from tbl
```

any help or suggestions are welcomed , It should be ideal if it's done without using cte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create an array based on the newline character, then [`UNNEST .. WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), so that you have a row number, and from there turn it again into a single row with `string_agg`:

```
SELECT string_agg(id || '.' || word,E'\n')
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  UNNEST(string_to_array(sample,E'\n')) WITH ORDINALITY j (word,id)
GROUP BY sample;

 string_agg 
------------
 1.I       +
 2.am      +
 3.Awesome
(1 Zeile)
```

If you want to split the items in many rows, just get rid of the `string_agg` and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT id || '.' || word
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  UNNEST(string_to_array(sample,E'\n')) WITH ORDINALITY j (word,id);

 ?column?  
-----------
 1.I
 2.am
 3.Awesome
(3 Zeilen)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=27d07ef1f1f1e7e78518319cbe88e0a8)